# Unable to Autowire through constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to Autowire a class through constructor.

```
@Component
public class Test<T extends Something>{

@Autowired
public Test(Class<T> entity)
doSomething(enity);
}
...
```

When I run the code I keep get the error message

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.test.Test required a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' in your configuration.
```

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong... There needs to be an instance of a class `Class` but I doubt that is something that is going to happen.

Comment: The argument of the constructor should be a concrete class.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?  I cannot think of any valid use case where it makes sense to wire in a class instance.  I'm eager/anxious to learn, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says you that it could not find Class class marked as Bean etc
So you need to have a class wanted to be injected declared as @Bean ,@Component etc.

Here is an example:

```
@Configuration
    public class Config {

        @Bean
        public<T> Class<T> tClass(){
            return (some class to be returned);// you need to generify or pass some type of class which you want 
        }

    }


    //Here is injecting with no problems
        @Component
        public class Test<T> {

            private Class<T> tClass;

            @Autowired
            public Test(Class<T> tClass) {
                this.tClass = tClass;
            }
        }
```

Some how its better do define such architecture which would be better in this case:

```
  public interface Foo<T> {

         Class<T> getClassFromType();
    }

@Component
public class FooIntegerImpl implements Foo<Integer>{


    @Override
    public Class<Integer> getClassFromType() {
        return Integer.class;
    }
}

@Component
public class FooStringImpl implements Foo<String>{

    @Override
    public Class<String> getClassFromType() {
        return String.class;
    }
}

@Component
public class Test {

    private List<Foo> foo;

    @Autowired
    public Test(List<Foo> foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}
```

For such purposes for example you can define generic API which would be common for all cases , actually you can define AbstractCrudOperations and define crud things when someone need to inherit it would define type of object which need to be in  and will have some methods defined

Actually in your case i dont know the logic what you want to implement but basic error is that Class could not be found as bean

I think this is helpful for you